# How to set random location of turtles within a zone?

Tags: netlogo

The following code creates three types of turtles (lobster, crab, fishermen) and three different "habitats" represented by different colors. How do I assign all lobsters to a random location within a specified habitat, such as habitat 1, and have them move randomly within this habitat?

```
globals []

breed [fishermen one.fisherman]
  breed [lobster one.lobster]
breed [crab one.crab]

lobster-own[alive.or.caught]
crab-own[alive.or.caught]
patches-own[habitat]

to setup-the-simulation
  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ;setup global variables here

  setup-environment

  setup-fishermen
  setup-lobster
  setup-crab
end

to setup-environment
  resize-world 0 80 0 44  ; min-x, max-x, min-y, max-y
  ask patches with [ pycor > 0 and pycor < 20]
  [
  set pcolor 104
  set habitat 1

  ]

  ask patches with [ pycor > 20 and pycor < 40]
  [
    set pcolor 84
    set habitat 2

  ]

  ask patches with [ pycor > 40 and pycor < 44]
  [ 
    set pcolor 34
    set habitat 3

  ]
end

to setup-lobster
  set-default-shape lobster "lobdraw"
  create-lobster 20 

  ask lobster [
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set size 5
    set color red]
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPQ5P.png)

I set all turtles to have a random-pxcor and random-pycor. The code `ask lobster [set habitat 1]` puts all the lobsters on one point within habitat 1 but I want it to be random.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler solution, given that you assigned specific colors for patches for each region. You can use the `one-of`. Here's how I would do it:

```
to setup-lobster
  set-default-shape lobster "lobdraw"
  create-lobster 20 

  ask lobster [
    move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 84]
    set size 5
    set color red]
end
```

Here is a detailed explanation of the `one-of` primitive and an interactive example: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/bind/primitive/one-of.html